# how to make a unique function for multiple codes of javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and I am wondering how to put it all on one function and give the id's of the span a unique id. So that way I dont have to have multiple instances off the same code each time. Right now if I want to have 3 countdowns I have to add his code three times and change the span id to a unique ID if i don't it will only work onces. So basically I want to be able to turn the JavaScript into one function so that I can call it without having to copy and paste it multiple times and also be able to have more than one countdown on a page by giving the span its own unique(random) id.

```
<script>
function showRemaining() {
    <?php echo "var end = new Date('". $row['expires'] ."');"; ?>

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour *24
    var timer;

    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0 ) {
       clearInterval( timer );
       document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

       return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor( (distance % _day ) / _hour );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (distance % _hour) / _minute );
    var seconds = Math.floor( (distance % _minute) / _second );

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Days: ' + days + ' ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += 'Hours: ' + hours + ' ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += 'Minutes: ' + minutes + ' ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += 'Seconds: ' + seconds;

}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>

<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few approaches I would recommend to make this function more reusable.

1. Pass the time of expiry as an argument, instead of hard-coding it to some database value that's printed by PHP code.
2. Break the implicit timer and UI (span) connection. Pass the element where this timer would be updated explicitly.
3. Manage the timer interval within the function itself. Right now it's spread between the function and global code (`setInterval`), which will make it difficult to reuse.

Here's the updated interface I propose for this function.

```
/*
  @param expiryTime timestamp when this countdown will expire
  @param elementToUpdate a reference to a DOM element that shows the timer
*/
function showRemainingTime(expiryTime, elementToUpdate)
```

Say if you have two spans with id's `a` and `b` which need to show this timer, then you would use this function as,

```
showRemainingTime(1325544453556, document.getElementById('a'));
showRemainingTime(1218290387102, document.getElementById('b'));
```